# Merging two data frames on 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rdYY.jpg)

The df1 has 92851 rows × 6 columns and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpYyD.jpg)

df2 has 92851 rows × 3 columns.

But when I try and merge the two dataframes into one, I get the cardinality as 255089 rows × 7 columns. It should be 92851 rows x 7 columns.

Why is this happening?

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['source','destination'])
```

Comment: probably because you don't have a 1-1 mapping on those columns between the 2 dataframes but it's impossible to say for sure without your actual data

Comment: Yes, 1-1 mapping aint there. In that case what should be done?

Comment: Up to you, it's your data, what is it you really want? Again without your data and a full explanation of what you're after it's difficult to comment

Comment: You should add some example data so we know what we are looking at.

Comment: I simply want to combine two dataframes into one. The Columns in df1 are [source,destination, shpment_size, payment_option,product_quantity,current_logistics_vendor] and the columns in df2 are [source,destination,shipment_zone]. The two key columns are [source, destination].

Comment: I guess the unique number of 'source' and 'destination' in both the dataframes are different, that is why it is expanding so much.

Comment: Check data types to ensure comparing the exact same data. Some sample data from both dataframes would help.

Comment: @KenSyme I have attached the sample data FYR

Comment: @hacker315 No , the unique number of items on both are the same.

Comment: Try `df1.merge(df2,on=['source','destination'])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` instead of merge.

SCALA code

```
val newDF = df1
               .join(df2, Seq("source", "destination"), "left_outer")
```

PYTHON code

```
newDF = df1
           .join(df2, ['source', 'destination'], 'left_outer')
```

Comment: NameError: name 'seq' is not defined